# ASP.NET C# - NavigateURL with RecordID combine

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. What I try to do is very basic, but I couldn't get it to work. If you see the NavigateURL link below, I try to combine the URL with "RefNum" from the database Recordset, but it keeps failing with "The server tag is not well formed." error.

I am not sure how to combine the URL with a record from recordset.

Please help,
Thanks.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UploadDate" SortExpression="UploadDate" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
     <asp:HyperLink   
        ID="HyperLink1"   
        runat="server" ForeColor="Blue"
        Text='<%# Eval("UploadDate") %>' 
        NavigateUrl="/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx?RefNum='<%# Bind("RefNum")%>'"                               
        />  
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `<%# Bind("RefNum")%>` they aren't needed for the query string anyway.

Comment: check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use eval with a formatter:

```
<asp:HyperLink   
        ID="HyperLink1"   
        runat="server" ForeColor="Blue"
        Text='<%# Eval("UploadDate") %>' 
        NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("RefNum", "/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx?RefNum={0}")%>'                               
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HyperLinkField` and its properties such as `DataNavigateUrlFields` to set fields

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="UploadDate" DataNavigateUrlFields="RefNum" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/ASPX/UploadContact/UploadContact.aspx?RefNum=={0}" Text="ID" />
```

Visit [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField.aspx) for more info